# Extract substring using Regex, but if string doesn't match Regex then retain it

Tags: java, regex

It might sound like another simple regex for the masters here, but its really giving me head-ache now :)

My problem is, I have following set of data and I would like to get rid of 'Name'.

1. Name's Question *E.g. John's Question, Bob's Question*
2. Information - Name *E.g. Information - Julie, Information - Richard, Information - David*
3. Select
4. Submit

As we can see 'Name' is only in couple of records, but not in others.

I have created two regex. I am using one application which internally uses JAVA to parse Regex. I can't write my own java code, I can just provide regex. :(

1. `(Question*(.*?))`
2. `(Information*(.*?))`

Problem is I am only getting "Question" record and system is not showing other three records.

I found the problem is, when I test regex as `(Question*(.*?))`, it does get rid of 'Name' in first example, but then it doesn't return anything in other three examples. I mean it return's blank. So when system is parsing 'Submit', in first transformation of 'Question' regex, it doesn't find 'Question' word, so it doesn't return anything.

What I would like to have is, that if 'Question' is not available, then system should return full string instead of deleting it. So, when system parse 'Submit' in first regex, it should return back 'Submit' as it is.

I don't know if my regex isn't correct

PS: 'Select' and 'Submit' are just two examples, there are atleast 20-25 other records, but there are only two records having '*Name*' in it.

Comment: Uhh. `if (QUESTION_RE.matches(input)) { /* do the replacement or extraction */ } else { return input; }`. You *are* allowed to use code around your regexes you know. (It might not be the most elegant way to do this what with the matching the same RE twice, but it'll do the job.)

Comment: I agree with above, add some logic to it.

Comment: Thanks @millimoose. Actually I am using one tool which just allows me to enter Regex. I can't write my own JAVA code. :( Sorry I should have mentioned in the question.

Comment: `Question*` is probably not what you want. That means the letters `Questio` and zero or more `n`s.

Comment: Please post the full text of the example, and what you expect to see.  It's really hard to understand what you want by "Select" and "Submit".

Comment: @MarkLakata.  I would like to see "Select" and "Submit" as it is. Those are just examples I have taken. What I want is to get rid of the name of customer and extract all other words in the above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex like this.
Since it's "or" the match will always turnout to be MatchGroup 1. (Assuming you perform "one match per line")

The Regex itself WILL match the whole string, but the First Matchgroup will only contain your keyword.

```
(?:.*?(Question)|(Information).*?|(Select|Submit))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](http://www.debuggex.com/r/uCGNJPYzvHcFtbfo)

Comment: Thanks @dognose... Atleast it did work by merging two regex into one. :) However, 'Select' and 'Submit' are just two examples, there are around atleast 20 to 25 other records, so instead of using 'Select' and 'Submit' specifically in regex, is it possible to update the regex to return all other records as it is?

Comment: Thanks @dognose... It worked. I just replaced 'Select' and 'Submit' with (.*) and all other ones with doesn't have 'Question' and 'Information' are returning full string and for 'Question' and 'Information' it is removing the 'Names'... Thanks for your help in resolving and helping in merging two regex into one :)